# The function map() or the function find() can not get the props I give to it, every time I use them, it turns out that I passed on a "null" to them

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

The file: chat.js

```
/*from chat.js */
@connect(
  state=>state,
  {getMsgList,sendMsg,recvMsg}
)
class Chat extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text:'',
      msg:[]
    }
  }
/*from chat.js */
render(){
    const {chatmsg} = this.props.chat
    console.log(chatmsg)
    return(
      <div>
        { this.state.msg.map( v=>{ return(<p key={v._id}>{v.content}</p>) } ) }
        <div className='stick-footer'>
          <List>
            <InputItem
            placeholder='please input'
            value = {this.state.text}
            onChange={v=>{
              this.setState({'text':v})
            }}
            extra={<span onClick={()=>this.handleSubmit()}>enter</span>}
            >infomation</InputItem>
          </List>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This is the initial version which runs correctly, `chatmsg` was print on the console of Chrome, which meant that I did get `chatmsg` from `this.props` at the time when it came into `render()`.

Console of Chrome logs out the property---'chamsg'

[image]

And here is my WebApp's state presented by redux-devtools

[image]

But then, when I wanted to replace `this.state.msg`'by `chatmsg` , I failed and I just could not find out the issue.

```
render(){
    const {chatmsg} = this.props.chat
    console.log(chatmsg)
    return(
      <div>
        { chatmsg.map( v=>{ return(<p key={v._id}>{v.content}</p>) } ) }
        <div className='stick-footer'>
          <List>
            <InputItem
            placeholder='please input'
            value = {this.state.text}
            onChange={v=>{
              this.setState({'text':v})
            }}
            extra={<span onClick={()=>this.handleSubmit()}>enter</span>}
            >infomation</InputItem>
          </List>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Did 'chatmsg' became 'null'? or what?

[image]

Here is what 'this.props' looks like and where it comes from:

[add 'console.log(this.props)' into 'render()'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugj8o.png)

[and, the props:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJGqr.png)

In fact, I just added something like below:

```
  { chatmsg?chatmsg.map( v=>{ return(<p key={v._id}>{v.content}</p>)}):"chatmsg is not loaded yet" }
```

perhaps at the very first time the page was loaded, 'chatmsg' was not 'render', but in a short time(maybe the second time the page was rendered), 'chatmsg' got everything it was supposed to own from store.

[every thing ok, thanks a lot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlPy5.png)

Comment: Can you please share what value you are getting in `this.props`?

Comment: I've posted 'this.props'.

Comment: As per `this.props`, `chat.chatmsg` is an array, you should not get this error. Not sure why `chatmsg.map` is reporting the issue.

Comment: Can you add componetWillRecieveProps(nextProps) method and do a console.log each time. This way you can know of the props being changed..

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have handled those issues. Later I will post what I have done to solve it.